# Combining parts of variables with numbers in their names

Tags: r

I am trying to combine parts of variables with numbers in their names. I have hundreds of variables named similarly to what I've included in the example below and therefore do not want to use a simple `cbind`.

The example:

```
test.1 <- matrix(1:10, nrow = 5)
test.2 <- matrix(11:20, nrow = 5)
test.3 <- matrix(21:30, nrow = 5)
```

I can easily use `do.call` to combine the variables, like so:

```
test.combi_works <- do.call(cbind, lapply(paste0("test.", 1:3), get))
```

But I only need the first column of each matrix.

First attempt:

```
test.combi <- do.call(cbind, lapply(paste0("test.", 1:3, "[,1]"), get))
Error in FUN(c("test.1[,1]", "test.2[,1]", "test.3[,1]")[[1L]], ...) : 
  object 'test.1[,1]' not found
```

Second attempt:

```
test.combi2 <- do.call(cbind, lapply(noquote(paste0("test.", 1:3, "[,1]")), get))
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : object 'test.1[,1]' not found
```

I assume this has to do with the fact that `get` works with character strings. I cannot simply bind all matrices together and then delete because I am actually working with lists whose further elements do not always have the same dimensions.

Comment: When you `paste0` you don't `subset`, so `get` tries to reach the object  test.1[,1] and it doesn't exist. I would try to use subset after the l'apply function but I am not familiar with the `do.call` functions

Comment: Why do you have "hundreds of variables" in you workspace? Good practice would be to put them savely in a list when they are created.

Comment: @Roland thanks for the tip. I am forced to do this, as I am working with NbClust and do not require all the indices. I must therefore create one object per index. I then need a summary matrix, so a list will unfortunately not help me in this case.

Comment: I have no idea what "NbClust" is, but I don't really believe your last two sentences. I suspect you simply haven't learned yet how to make proper use of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a new function to `do.call` to do both the getting and the subsetting. As @Llopis pointed out, the problem is that `test.1[,1]` is not just an object; it's an object (`test.1`) with a function applied to it (`[,1]` is the function call). Because `get` only works on objects, you should get the object first and then apply the subsetting  function.

For a single object, this would look like:

```
myfun <- function(x) { get(x)[,1] }
myfun("test.1")
```

And you can pass the same function into `lapply`:

```
test.combi_works <- do.call(
  cbind, lapply(paste0("test.", 1:3), function(x) { get(x)[,1] } )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution without using `paste` and character strings

```
do.call(cbind, 
        lapply(mget(ls()[grep('test',ls())]), function(x) x[ , 1]))
```

and I think what @Roland is trying to say, subtly, is that keeping your workspace in order is a good basic practice that will avoid errors later. Lists are a great and easy way to do that.

```
     test.1 test.2 test.3
[1,]      1     11     21
[2,]      2     12     22
[3,]      3     13     23
[4,]      4     14     24
[5,]      5     15     25
```